# Lotus Notes : How do I apply a View to all folders

Tags: lotus-notes

I have set up a view for my mail Inbox, I'd like to use it for (all) other folders, how do I achieve this? I know for a fact it's possible in Outlook ("apply this view to all folders" or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

You could probably modify the 'upgrade folder design' agent that ships with notes or just write a simple agent to do it.

I think the code you really need is:

```
@UpdateViewDesign(targetView, sourceView)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Ytria's viewEZ](http://www.ytria.com/WebSite.nsf/WebPageRequest/Solutions_viewEZen?OpenDocument&Lang=en) plug-in.  But it seems very complex and I still have to figure out how to use it.

Comment: Ytria has some web videos they can send you that cover a lot of random things. Once you contact them, they try really hard to sell you stuff though and will keep contacting you, at least in my experience.